# Using angular.mock.inject in karma gives "TypeError: Cannot read property '$injector' of null"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tdd, karma-runner

I am trying to do some basic Unit testing for AngularJS using Karma. All the tests I have written seem syntactically correct. But I am having a problem at the most basic step, i.e the beforeEach part of the code. When I try running the test, I get the following problem

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$injector' of null
at Object.workFn (http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/vesriram/Documents/AngularJS%20project/vendor/js/angular-mocks.js:1698:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/adapter/lib/angular-scenario.js:26360:54)
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.forEach (http://localhost:9876/adapter/lib/angular-scenario.js:9593:11)
```

I have been trying to solve this problem for the past 36 hours and have had no luck so far. As far as I can see, noone else seems to be having this problem. This makes me think that I am possibly doing something stupid. I would really appreciate any help you people could give me. I will be happy to post any additional code that you need (so long as I am at liberty to divulge it).

The relevant code is the following-

**app.js**

```
var sell_page = angular.module("sell_page", ['ui.bootstrap']);

sell_page.controller('ItemTitleController', ['$scope','listingInformationService', '$location',function($scope, listingInformationService, $location) {
    $scope.itemNames = getAllItemNames();
    $scope.draftItems = getAllSavedDrafts();
    document.getElementById("categorySelection").style.visibility = "hidden";

    ------bunch of code-------
}]);
```

**controllersSpec.js**

```
describe("Unit: Testing Controllers", function() {

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sell_page'));

it('should have a ItemTitleController controller', function() {
    expect(sell_page.ItemTitleController).not.to.equal(null);
});


describe("ItemTitleController", function() {
    var scope;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('sell_page'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, listingInformationService, $location, $controller) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var controller = $controller('ItemTitleController', {
            $scope : scope
        });
    }));

    it("should display xxx properly", function() {
        --some code---
    });

});
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
basePath = '';

files = [
   JASMINE,
   JASMINE_ADAPTER,
   '../vendor/js/angular.min.js',
   '../vendor/js/angular.js',
   '../vendor/js/angular-mocks.js',
   '../vendor/js/angular-scenario.js',
   ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
   ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
   '../app/js/*.js',
   'e2e/*.js',
   'midway/*.js',
   'unit/*.js',    
];

exclude = [
];

reporters = ['progress'];
port = 9876;
runnerPort = 9100;
colors = true;
logLevel = LOG_INFO;
autoWatch = true;
browsers = ['Chrome'];
captureTimeout = 60000;
singleRun = false;
```

Comment: ANGULAR_SCENARIO and ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER are for E2E testing so need not be included.. I don't think that's your problem though.

Comment: Yeah, I have e2e tests as well. I have not included them coz they are working fine and are irrelevant to my current problem. :)

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I honestly don't know if this is the fix at all, and it probably only works for Mocha, but I was running into the same thing and I changed the first beforeEach bit to this:

```
beforeEach(function() { module('myApp'); });
```

and it seems to be working better.  It seems like the timing of the angular.mocks.module call works out better if you let the testing framework (mocha in my case) have a wrapped version of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I commonly run into this error when the issue is simply an un-closed `)` or `}`

Outside of that, an approach to debug the issue might be to simplify until the problem goes away. That is, start removing large portions of code, a bit at a time, until you've "binary-searched" for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

In my case, this error occurs when you use **angular 1.0.8** and **angular-mocks 1.0.8** with the newer version of Jasmine (2.0.0+, not so new actually)

angular-mock assumes some internal variable in Jasmine and it doesn't exist anymore in the new version.For more detail, see this one https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5632.

The solution is either upgrade your Angular (not possible in my case) or downgrade your Jasmine.

If you use Grunt to run karma, downgrade your karma-jasmine to version '~0.1.0' will fix this issue. This version includes jasmine, so you should also remove 'jasmine-core' from your devDependencies. The set of devDependencies below worked for me.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt-karma": "^0.10.1",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.15",
}
```